# how to focus textarea in kendoui draggable object?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, draggable

I can't focus textarea,edit,select text,change cursorpostion of textarea in KendoUI draggable as JqueryUI "cancle" configuration

example

http://jsfiddle.net/86yTG/1/

html:

```
<div class="drag">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

css:

```
.drag{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drag').kendoDraggable({
        hint: function(e){
            return e.clone();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a `click` on your `textarea` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.drag').kendoDraggable({
      hint: function (e) {
          return e.clone();
      }
   }).find('textarea').on('click', function () {  //<-----add from here
      $(this).focus();
   });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86yTG/2/)

Here you have to bind an event to the textarea to get the focus.

Comment: thanks, but i can't select text or change mouse CursorPosition of textarea :(

Comment: okay! but why you want to use mouse there you can use `left,right` arrow keys.